# How to negate the Authorize attribute in a development environment - .Net 7

Tags: c#, .net, authorization

I'm currently in the process of migrating some code inherited from my predecessor in my role that is littered with the following directives in controllers:

```
#if DEBUG == false
   [Authorize]
#endif
```

I don't really like this implementation as it creates too much noise in the file and looks messy having each method that requires auth in production decorated with this snippet. I therefore want to move the authorize attribute to the top of each controller and decorate the methods that are publicly accessible with the [AllowAnonymous] atrribute instead which makes it really clear which endpoints need auth in production and which ones don't.

The issue I face is having my application remove the authorize attribute or ignore it when we are running in development / debug mode. The solution and all projects target .Net 7 but it was originally updated from .Net 5 so rather than having the single program.cs file, we are still utilising Program.cs and Startup.cs. I am not looking to change this as this is what the rest of my team are used to but any future projects will use the new style.

There are a number of solutions I've looked at on here that suggest I do the following in my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider){
  
...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();
            }
            else
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }
        });
```

However, our use Endpoint declaration uses the following and if I revert to the above, our swagger page is no longer displayed upon running the application:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "default",
   pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
}
```

I've also tried applying the follwoing to my Configure services method:

```
services.AddControllers(opts =>
            {
                opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
            });
```

But when I attempt to call an endpoint decorated with the [Authorize] attribute it still applies the authorization and returns a 401 unauthorized respone when making the request in Swagger. Obviously the above is not the full code for brevity as I needed to create a private variable in Startup.cs to store the IWebHostEnvironment so it could be used in configure services but you get the idea.

I've confirmed that in debug mode it is going down the correct page and applying allow anonymous on startup but I'm at a loss at how to get this working whilst also being able to utilise Swagger. Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated as I've already read about 6 or 7 SO posts relating to this and none of them work.